# How do I specify which string of an ArrayAdapter to use for a ListFragment?

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-listfragment

I have a simple ListFragment to display a list of custom objects.

`MyListFragment extends ListFragment`

```
private ArrayList<CustomObject> mArrayOfCustomObject;
private ArrayAdapter<CustomObject> mAdapter;

mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<CustomObject>(context,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item1,
    mArrayOfCustomObject);
setListAdapter(mAdapter);
```

The problem is that I get a long list that looks like this:

```
com.example.CustomObject@40XXXXXX
com.example.CustomObject@40XXXXXX
com.example.CustomObject@40XXXXXX
com.example.CustomObject@40XXXXXX
....
```

I am doing it this way because I want to be able to click on an item and display more information about it. This is why I'm linking the adapter to a `List<CustomObject>` rather than `List<String>`.

**I know that a `List<String>` would display it correctly, but then each item would just be a random string with no connection to it's CustomObject.**

What's the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from creating your own custom Adapter,for an easy fix just override the `toString()` method in `CustomObject` and have it return something readable. When the Adapter you're using populates its rows, it calls `toString()` on your CustomObject then displays that result.

Say that you had a field in your `CustomObject` called `timePassed`

```
long timePassed = 100000l;
@Override
  public String toString()
  {
    return "Time passed: " + timePassed + " milliseconds";
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I considered this but I was hesitant to modify CustomObject since I didn't make it, but maybe this is the best way to go. Ty!

Comment: @RowanFreeman it takes the least amount of work on your end since you don't have to make a custom Adapter as well. I guess you could also set up parallel Lists and control both at the same time so you can avoid making a custom Adapter, but that's just wasteful.